# Android lsmod output

Tags: android

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the lsmod output from Android 4.0.3. What all those "Live ADDR" entries mean?

```
option 14926 0 - Live 0xbf12b000
usb_wwan 9419 1 option, Live 0xbf124000
cdc_acm 15150 0 - Live 0xbf11b000
g_crypto 11918 0 - Live 0xbf0cc000
g_wmt_cmoscam 1421 0 - Live 0xbf0c8000
g_wmt_v4l2_cmos 68606 1 g_wmt_cmoscam, Live 0xbf0b1000
g_wmt_v4l2 5135 1 g_wmt_v4l2_cmos, Live 0xbf0ab000
g_wmt_ve_h264 11644 0 - Live 0xbf0a5000
g_wmt_ve_com 9021 1 g_wmt_ve_h264, Live 0xbf09e000
g_wmt_vd_vpx 65936 0 - Live 0xbf088000
g_wmt_vd_rv 735 0 - Live 0xbf084000
g_wmt_vd_vc1 713 0 - Live 0xbf080000
g_wmt_vd_h264 715 0 - Live 0xbf07c000
g_wmt_vd_h263 715 0 - Live 0xbf078000
g_wmt_vd_divx 715 0 - Live 0xbf074000
g_wmt_vd_mpeg4 717 0 - Live 0xbf070000
g_wmt_vd_mpeg2 717 0 - Live 0xbf06c000
g_wmt_vd_jdec 18829 0 - Live 0xbf063000
g_wmt_lock 2881 5 - Live 0xbf05f000
g_wmt_vd_com 158558 12 g_wmt_vd_vpx,g_wmt_vd_rv,g_wmt_vd_vc1,g_wmt_vd_h264,g_wmt_vd_h263,g_wmt_vd_divx,g_wmt_vd_mpeg4,g_wmt_vd_mpeg2,g_wmt_vd_jdec, Live 0xbf032000
mali 102375 6 - Live 0xbf00d000
ump 27968 11 mali, Live 0xbf000000
```

I'm asking this because I use the exact same kernel to boot Ubuntu, and this is the output for lsmod on Ubuntu

```
option                 14926  0 
g_wmt_lock              2881  0 
g_wmt_vd_jdec          18829  0 
g_wmt_vd_mpeg2           717  0 
g_wmt_vd_mpeg4           717  0 
g_wmt_vd_divx            715  0 
g_wmt_vd_h263            715  0 
g_wmt_vd_h264            715  0 
g_wmt_vd_vc1             713  0 
g_wmt_vd_rv              735  0 
g_wmt_vd_vpx           65936  0 
g_wmt_ve_h264          11644  0 
g_wmt_ve_com            9021  1 g_wmt_ve_h264
g_wmt_cmoscam           1421  0 
g_wmt_v4l2_cmos        68606  1 g_wmt_cmoscam
g_wmt_v4l2              5135  1 g_wmt_v4l2_cmos
g_wmt_vd_com          158558  9 g_wmt_vd_jdec,g_wmt_vd_mpeg2,g_wmt_vd_mpeg4,g_wmt_vd_divx,g_wmt_vd_h263,g_wmt_vd_h264,g_wmt_vd_vc1,g_wmt_vd_rv,g_wmt_vd_vpx
g_crypto               11918  0 
mali                  102375  0 
ump                    27968  1 mali
cdc_acm                15150  0 
usb_wwan                9419  1 option
rt3070sta_rtl8188     442205  0
```

HDMI, Camera, etc. are not working on Ubuntu, although the same modules are loaded on both OS's. That's why I asked about the Live and ADDR columns. I'd like to know if this has anything to do with the lack of functionality on Ubuntu.

Comment: what do you mean by camera and hdmi are not working on ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know, for example, on Android, if I do a lsusb after boot, it doesn't show that the camera is attached to a USB port. But after I launch the camera application, somehow the camera is mounted (chekced through dmesg and lsusb).

Comment: However, when I boot Ubuntu, the camera is never recognised at all (check via dmesg and lsusb). If I connect a wire between a powered USB port and the USB port where the camera is attached to, I give that USB port a power supply, and dmesg and lsusb detect the camera.

Answer (score 2):

`lsmod` just reads from the file `/proc/modules` (it actually calls cat `/proc/modules`)

This is the same for many UNIX like OSes:

```
The first column contains the name of the module.

The second column refers to the memory size of the module, in bytes.

The third column lists how many instances of the module are currently loaded. A value of zero represents an unloaded module.

The fourth column states if the module depends upon another module to be present in order to function, and lists those other modules.

The fifth column lists what load state the module is in: Live, Loading, or Unloading are the only possible values.

The sixth column lists the current kernel memory offset for the loaded module. This information can be useful for debugging purposes, or for profiling tools such as oprofile.
```

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-modules.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I just edited my original answer with the purpose of asking this. Would you mind to take a look?